# Python post api request

Tags: python

I need to make a post into an API. I'm working with python. I'm new on this and I can't create an ad tag. I tried with create a dict with the api example information but it didn't work. When I run the `>>> sitios_creados`, the answer is ''
and when I run `sites.status_code`I reveice `415.
I don't understand why because if you see in my code, I did a right post python requests before with the token

I must to take the publisherid and with it and the token id create the ad tag.

my publisherid is: 15663

my code:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ',
}

data = [
  ('grant_type', 'password'),
  ('username', ''),
  ('password', ''),
]

response = requests.post('http://api.site.com/v1/oauth/generateOauthToken', headers=headers, data=data)
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
token = json_data['access_token'].encode("utf-8")


headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token)
}


sites = requests.post('http://api.site.com/v1/inventorymgmt/publisherAdTag?entityId=15663', headers=headers, data=data)
sitios_creados = sites.content
```

Api information example:

```
URL: http://api.site.com/v1/inventorymgmt/publisherAdTag?entityId=2685
Method: POST
Request Body:
{
    "publisherId": 2685,
    "publisherSiteurl": "http://example.org",
    "adTagName": "THIS_IS_TEST_DEMAND_5",
    "adCodeTypeId": 1,
    "foldPlacementId": 1,
    "adTypeId": 3,
    "pagePlacementId": 1,
    "adExpansionDirectionId": 1,
    "adSize": {

        "name": null,
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "id": 9
    },
    "adTagPlacements": [{
        "adTagPlacementId": 0,
        "linkOnlyToGeo": false,
        "ecpm": 1,
        "adScript": "THIS IS DEMO SCRIPT",
        "currency": 1
    }],
    "adTagCustomParamMap": [{
        "name": "kadcarrier",
        "macroValue": "techno.carrier"
    }, {
        "name": "kadcity",
        "macroValue": "geo.city"
    }]
}
```

Comment: "it didn't work" is vague.  Did you get an error?  If so what did it say?  If you didn't, how are you confirming it didn't work?

Comment: I added what I have as the answer. @jrefior

Comment: And what about other clues from the HTTP response?  For example, did the response include a 202 Accepted status code?

Comment: If I do `sites.status_code` I see `415`. That is you are saying? My apologies but I'm a nob so it's very difficult to me @jrefior

Comment: Yes, that status code is helpful, I suggest you edit your question to add that.  Was there a body or any other data in the response?  415 is Unsupported Media Type (see, e.g., https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html).

Comment: I have `415` only. I added it on the question. I need to convert the api information json to a post requests but I don't know how. I tried with a `variable = json data` and added it into the `requests.post` but I receive the same result @jrefior

Answer (score 0):

Is it an API for a website?

When yes, you can do a network analysis in the developer tool of your browser and copy the curl command of the POST package.

Then you surf to [curl.trillworks.com](https://curl.trillworks.com/) and convert the curl command it into a Python POST request.

Inside of your python request you can modify the values.